# Call artisan command from the same command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

In the handle of your custom Laravel command, can you call the command again? Like this, described using sort of pseudo-code:

```
public function handle() {
    code..
    code..

    $this->importantValue = $this->option('value'); //value is 'hello'

    if(something) {
        //call of the same command is made, but with different arguments or options
        //command does stuff and ends successfully
        $this->call('myself' [
            'value' => 'ahoy'
        ];
        //I expect the handle to be returned to the original command
    }

    var_dump($this->importantValue); //this equals 'ahoy'

}
```

Why is this? What does that newly called command has in common with the original within which it had been called?

EDIT: The newly called command would not reach the condition `something` **it would not call itself** again (forever). The original command seems to pick up from where it left (before calling itself the first and only time) yet it seems it has had inherited the "children's" variables.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that calling `Artisan::call()` instead of `$this->call()` might avoid that problem (note that avoiding is not the same as solving)...

@t-maxx: I'm getting the exact same issue and I'm not sure that @ben understands.

I have a command that is recursive, based on an argument, `depth`.  The `depth` argument is set to a protected property as one of the first steps in `handle()`.  Then, if `depth` is greater than zero, it calls itself (via `$this->call()`), but passing `$this->depth - 1`.  I watch each successive call and it just goes down and down and down, never plateauing or bouncing up was the recursion would allow and as one would expect.

So...while I'm not 100% sure what's going on, I'm thinking of getting the `depth` option once, but passing it around as a variable (versus a property on the object).  This is ugly, I think, but it may be the only solution until this is recognized and resolved. On the other hand, it could be that we're both doing the wrong thing.

Calling `Artisan::call()` for me leads to other issues that I'd rather avoid. The command I'm working with writes to a file and I don't want a bunch of separate commands competing for the same file.

Comment: Sorry...one last thing.  I do think that calling `Artisan::call()` instead of `$this->call()` might avoid that problem (note that avoiding is not the same as solving)....but for me I think it leads to other issues that I'd rather avoid.  (The command I'm working with writes to a file and I don't want a bunch of separate commands competing for the same file.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [Programmatically Executing Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) using `Artisan::call`

```
Artisan::call('myself', [
    'value' => 'ahoy'
]);
```

Comment: The problem is well defined in my original question. It is that the context of the original call is lost after completation of the newly called command.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, it is working fine and can you paste the real code to describe your problem? pseudo code cannot proof your assumption